# Images disappear when Django debug=False

Tags: django, image

When preparing to deploy my Django website to production, of course I turn the "debug" flag to "false" in my settings file.  For some reason, all my images stop appearing.  Here is my call to the image(s) in my template(s):

```
<div id='photo1'>
<img src="{% static 'app/image.png' %}" alt="Image Text">
</div>
```

Appreciate suggestions for formatting my image links so they survive transition to production!

Comment: you are likely serving your images in a way that production mode does not allow. Do you have nginx or anything in front of your app?  Are you running "collectstatic" as part of your production build process also?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: On AWS, I was running the app in cloud9 with the same image rendering issue upon transition to Debug = False.  Transition of the app to Elastic Beanstalk results in the "Congratulations" banner but doesn't actually run my app, and the latest cloud9 "runserver" command results in a slick "Oops VFS Connection does not exist," so have some substantial troubleshooting to do on this complex app.. had hoped for an easy answer on the image rendering, but from your response, I gather my link (and implied "static" home for my images) is fine.

Answer (score 0):

When going on production you need to serve your images from a source other than your local machine. On the internet. Lets say AWS (amazon). There are some free and paid options. In general you need to create an account there, fix some settings there and adjust your django settings.py to point there when Debug = False. Your collectstatic will run there, static dirs etc will be linked there when you deploy for production. There are tutorials on how to do it. When running on development mode you can switch back your settings and serve your static and media from your computer again.